# Layout rejects to read TextView,ImageViews,Any view at all

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

The xml code: -->Also tried with ImageView and buttonView, Picker, and so on, it won't read data from this xml.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="This is a textview."
        android:background="#f00"></TextView>
```

Java code where i set the view to the activity containing this XML.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


    }
```

Now, what i **SHOULD** see is this:
[image: Image of the CORRECT picture in the android studio and what i want to see]

What i **REALLY** see is this:
[image: What i see on my phone]

Also i have declared the java in the android Manifest.

maybe it'll help but This activity is reached by pressing 2 buttons from 2 different activities, I've tested the same logic with a new project and it works, but it doesn't work on my main project.

Comment: post your full xml code

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/5L13MNC.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER**: There was some weird bug i myself don't understand, i removed the java code and re-added it again, and now it suddenly works, Thanks for suggestions everyone.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the part where you start your activity with Intents is right.

It should be something like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class):
startActivity(i);
```

if there's no problem with that, try checking your layout's name for any chance of conflict.

At the last try changing your OnCreate to :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
}
```

Looks like there is no problem in your XML, but also check the root of your layout.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the intent in my code, i am sure of it.
and for the second one, i've tried to change the name, same issue.
the full xml(contains rootView) is

http://i.imgur.com/5L13MNC.jpg